# how to know when I need to clear drupal 7 cache in a custom module when it sets variables in its hook_install or in its hook_enable?

Tags: caching, drupal-7

I am building custom modules which install other modules and set their settings. (to make it quicker to have modules and their settings I use)

I run into following issue: when I moved all my custom modules onto my prod environment php freezes without logging any error. I could get rid of this error by clearing drupal cache than refreshing modules list than installing next module. If I don't refresh modules list I still get php freezing. I am setting variables to set my modules settings.

On my development environment I don't get this issue.

Any idea how to know when I need to clear drupal cache in a custom module when it sets variables as well?

Or if it is likely that I have another issue what would it be?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? How do you deploy your code to production?

Comment: I getting only a WSOD. No error messages on screen or in php log files however I've set them both. I've tar-ed all my files and uploaded them to the server than changed my settings.php. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

Is your prod environment identical to your dev (OS, PHP version, database, etc)?

You could try to rebuild the registry (drush rr or the module  https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild); a faulty registry is a usual suspect with WSODs.

Try setting error_reporting=E_ALL / display_errors=on on your index.php; that could give you some pointers.

Comment: Well, of course they are not identical :(
Actually I'm not sure what happened but it started working fine after a few days. Very weird.

Comment: By identical I mean the same setup (same apache version and configuration, same php version and configuration, etc). They could be if you're using Vagrant or other types of virtual machines.

Comment: They differ slightly. Like minor version of differences of server softwares. Unfortunately I believe I can not reproduce the issue as it is working fine now.